# One email address, two usernames

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I initially set up a Minecraft account on my son's laptop under my email address with, let's say, '*username 1*'. Later I set up another account on my iPhone - let's call it '*username 2*', and I have purchased many worlds, skins, etc., under this '*username 2*'.

Now I'm sick of him playing on my phone all the time, but every time I log into his laptop with my email address and password for '*username 2*', it says "incorrect password". If I enter my email and '*username 1*'s password, it goes into the boring first account with no purchases!
I also have to say the laptop is using a purchased Java edition of Minecraft.

How do I log my son into the laptop using '*username 2*' and access all of the worlds/skins and purchases?

Comment: IPhone? Which variant of Minecraft are you actually playing? Regular Minecraft does not exist for iPhones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the Bedrock edition from the Microsoft Store. It is cross-platform and has all the same content as the iOS version.
If you currently only own the Java version, you will have to buy the game again from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Bedrock Edition is only free if you bought the Java Edition before October 19th, 2018. https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10

Comment: Huh, I think I bought mine right around that time  I guess I got lucky then.